# Need to removeObserver before deallocation, but ARC forbids overriding dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, observer-pattern, dealloc

I've got a class, `RA_CustomCell : UITableViewCell`. Some instances of this class register to be observers of a variable `currentLocation` in another class `RA_LocationSingleton`.

RA_CustomCell.m

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self registerAsListener]
}

-(void)registerAsListener
{
    if ([self.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"locationcell1"])
    {
        [[RA_LocationSingleton locationSingleton]
               addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"currentLocation"
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                   context:nil];
    }
}
```

However, these cells get deallocated naturally when the user navigates backwards. The problem is that when the currentLocation variable updates itself, I get the following crash error:

```
*** -[RA_CustomCell retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9bd9890
```

Unfortunately, I cannot override `-dealloc` because I am using ARC, and typing `[super dealloc]` produces the following alert:

```
ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc'
```

My question is, how best should I manage my location listeners to avoid this kind of crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use dealloc without calling `[super dealloc]`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
   [[RA_LocationSingleton locationSingleton] removeObserver:self
                                                 forKeyPath:@"currentLocation"
                                                    context:nil];
}
```

From the apple doc on [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes, ARC Enforces New Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW14):

> Custom dealloc methods in ARC do not require a call to [super dealloc]
>   (it actually results in a compiler error). The chaining to super is
>   automated and enforced by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `dealloc`, it's just that `[super dealloc]` is called for you automatically.

It is explained in the apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

"Custom dealloc methods in ARC do not require a call to [super dealloc] (it actually results in a compiler error). The chaining to super is automated and enforced by the compiler."